# Pass the Clientcredential in clientobject model in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am passing the use credential with hardcode values. Below is the code:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strsiteURL))
{   
      NetworkCredential cre = new NetworkCredential("strUserName", "StrPassword", "StrDomain");
      ctx.Credentials = cre;
}
```

I want to pass the User credentials dynamically, who is loged in to the sharepoint application.

Please let me know how can I do this
Thanks,
KK

Answer (score 1):

Use [CredentialCache.DefaultCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the system credentials for the current security context in which the application is running:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
      context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
      //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. When I replace with the given code.I am getting Invalid Request.If I hard code the user credentials I am able to Insert the record In Document Library

Answer (score 0):

try your code with below impersonation way:

```
        WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
        if (!WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem)
        {
            ctx = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero);                
        }
```